# Show that the $\sigma -field$ generated by $S$ and the $\sigma$-field generated by $S'$ satisfy $F_S\subseteq F_{S'}$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $S$ and $S'$ be two sets of events such $S\subseteq S'$. Show that the $\sigma -field$ generated by $S$ and the $\sigma$-field generated by $S'$ satisfy $F_S\subseteq F_{S'}$.

I really can't grasp the slightest idea of how to start the proof. Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\sigma$-field generated by a set $S$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-fields containing $S$.

If $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-field containing $S^{\prime}$, then it also contains $S$. Therefore the intersection of all $\sigma$-fields containing $S^{\prime}$ contains $S$, i.e. $S\subset F_{S^{\prime}}$.

But $F_S$ is the intersection of all $\sigma$-fields containing $S$, hence is contained in $F_{S^{\prime}}$.

Comment: That is such a clear proof! Thanks a million!